# is possible to "hash" a ssim from original image so i dont have to read the image again?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, ffmpeg

Currently I started working on a personal project where you will constantly receive images, similar or not. Every new image received do I need to loop through absolutely every other image already saved to compare ssim?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking or attempting to do. But SSIM is a comparison between two images, you need the two full images to compute their SSIM. You cannot compute the SSIM of an image against the hash of another image. You can compare hashes of two images, but then you only know if their are bit for bit identical or not, you cannot obtain a similarity score using hashes.

Comment: I guess you want something like this: https://realpython.com/fingerprinting-images-for-near-duplicate-detection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **No** you can't recover the image from SSIM and **Yes** you'd have to loop over all images for comparison.
However you may look at image compression to have faster evaluation of the SSIM.

Some example images would be welcome for a better answer.